# How to display the number of elements of a view with twig?

Tags: views, 8, theming

How to display the number of elements of a view with twig?

I created a view of 50 products with a pagination (12 products per page).

If I type the following code:

```
{{ drupal_view_result('boutique_page_produit', 'block_2')|length }}
```

This displays the number of items in the view's page (12). I want the total element number of my element (50).

How to do this ?

One solution would be to create a second view without pagination, but is there another solution ?

Comment: What’s wrong with using the result summary in the header of the view?

Comment: @Kevin I need to display only the number of items in a view in another view.

Comment: @Kevin If not, what is the twig code to display only the summary of the results? (without displaying the entire view)

Comment: I don't think this is doable in twig alone - I think you would have to preprocess it to execute the view, and get the result count, then pass that in as a new variable.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you. So the only solution is to create another view without pagination.

Answer (score 0):

The total items is available in views.view.html.twig like:

```
{{ view.total_rows }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the views query and execute a `->count()` on it :

```php
$total_rows = $view->query->query()->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
```